# Overlap Bar chart android

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to create overlapped bar chart for my application. I know about stacked bar chart and sub column bar chart. but is it possible to implement the overlapped bar chart like present in the  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement. I am using MpAndroidChart https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart for generating stacked bar chart and sub column bar chart.

Comment: You can use `Combined Chart`.

Comment: I don't think i can achieve this in Combined chart. If it is possible please provide me some sample.

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java. Here you can use two bar chart with different data.

Comment: I can use two bar chart but i cannot use overlay barchart